# Characterization of exact groups via the existence of amenable actions on unital C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

It is known that a discrete group $G$ is exact if and only if it admits an amenable action on a *compact* topological space.  Would it also be true that $G$ is necessarily exact when it admits an amenable action on a *unital* C*-algebra?

Comment: Could your remind us of the definition of what it means for a G-action on a noncommutative Cstar-algebra to be amenable? Is this the definition in e.g. Brown-Ozawa's book?

Comment: @Yemon, you are 100% correct. This was originally formulated by Anantharaman-Delaroche following ideas of Zimmer.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the definition (4.3.1 in Brown and Ozawa) that if G acts amenably on a unital C*-algebra A then it also acts amenably on the center of A, which provide an amenable action on a compact space?

Comment: Yep, you are right @Caleb.  This settles it!

Comment: @Caleb,  you will probably see this, but in any case let me point out that I am posting a new version of this question in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255246/characterization-of-exact-groups-via-the-existence-of-amenable-actions-on-unital